# AES256 String encryption on PHP and decryption on iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, encryption, aes

i have this on my php code:

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$key = "bla";
$text = json_encode($rows);
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv)
print base64_encode($crypttext);
```

and this one the iphone:

```
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bla.com/myinfo.php"]  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    response = [[NSData base64DataFromString:response] AESDecryptWithPassphrase:@"bla"];
    response = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(response);
```

but it doesn't work, anyone has a method that works?
  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet, you're stumbling upon a padding issue. I addressed this topic in three SO answers, so you likely find the solution in one of those answers:

- [Difference in PHP encryption from iOS and .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411645/difference-in-php-encryption-from-ios-and-net/4411732#4411732)
- [AES Encrypt in C#, decrypt in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192658/aes-encrypt-in-c-decrypt-in-php/4196648#4196648)
- [DES Encryption in PHP and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251289/des-encryption-in-php-and-c/4256728#4256728)